# Double slash in URL to user profile in featured photos block

Tags: bug, status-completed, featured-photo, links

I open [Photo SE front page](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) and see the following:

[image]

The arrow I added points to a link to photo author profile. In this case the link there is

```
https://photo.stackexchange.com/users//9347/cody
```

note the double slash between `users` and the user id number.

It doesn't hurt - the link "works" just fine - but it looks untidy.